# Posting data in django application,returning response as false,please tell where is error

Tags: django

Request is `{"name":"vikas","age":20}`

I am using following code to return the response from server

```
URL : "localhost:3000"
status_code, employee_data = webutils.make_request(settings.URL + "get_data/", 
method='POST', 
body=json.dumps(request.data), 
json=True)

return Response(employee_data )
```

When I am using the postman,accessing the url `localhost:3000/get_data/`
It is returning the correct format.

But through django framework returning the response as false.
Please let me know the following code,I have written is correct in django

```
webutils.make_request(settings.URL + "get_data/", method='POST', body=json.dumps(request.data), json=True)
```

Comment: Is `URL : "localhost:3000" status_code, employee_data = webutils.make_request(settings.URL + "get_data/", method='POST', body=json.dumps(request.data), json=True)

return Response(employee_data )` the actual code you have in your *.py files? Looks like it is no a valid python code.

Comment: I have written URL in setting.py file.   I am modifying the code  status_code, employee_data = webutils.make_request("localhost:3000/get_data/", method='POST', body=json.dumps(request.data), json=True)                                          return Response(employee_data )

Comment: What type of object is `request`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try with httpresponse class json dump data.
2. Try with Python requests library

Comment: I tried with All the above written things....I observed in response;response is as following :----                                                                                          [WARNING 2016-06-25 13:
01:33,663 requestmiddleware.py:50 - process_response() ]  ** response_data ** {"
response_status": 200, "error": "No X-CORRELATION-ID Found in Header", "response
_body": "false"}  But once we are accesing the same url with postman,I am getting response

Comment: Tried with all possible headers?? Could you please paste the whole url that you are requesting??

Comment: webutils.make_request("localhost:3000/get_data/", method='POST', body=json.dumps(request.data), json=True)

Comment: Add http as prefix in url and test it

Comment: thanks Rajesh...it is working...can you give me some good tutorial link...